# Broken text encoding in various parts of the Guild Wars 2 UI

Tags: technical-issues, guild-wars-2

Since day 1 of playing Guild Wars 2, I've been plagued by a text-encoding issue in various parts of the UI. It seems that anywhere that certain types of punctuation (bullet points, for example) are intended to appear, other characters are rendered instead, such as Ā, Ą, Ē, Ě, etc.

I first thought this was due to my operating system's region setting at first, but even though I've changed my region setting back to "English (United States)," the issue still persists. I haven't been able to find any discussion about this issue aside from a single buried thread on the official forums with no replies, so I'm not sure how common this behavior is.

Is there a known cause and/or fix for this issue?

Quick technical specs: Windows Vista 64-bit, Core 2 Duo 3.16GHz, 8GB RAM, GeForce GTX 285 1GB

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like the right font to me. I would run an image to refresh your game files.
`gw2.exe -image` and leave it overnight, that might solve the issue.

Comment: @DavidYell: I'll give that a shot tonight and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if not there is a `-repair` option as well apparently :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found! (Sort of.)

First, I tried running `gw2.exe -image` and `-repair`, which didn't make any difference.

However, I remembered that I had set "Interface Size" under the graphics options to "Large." Setting the interface size back to Normal resolved the issue. Upon further testing, "Small", "Normal", and "Larger" settings all display the punctuation correctly -- only "Large" seems to produce the issue for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for the discovery. I was about to write to ArenaNet and bash them for not knowing about unicode in the 21st century

Comment: @MaciejHehl bash them for not implementing it correctly then.

Comment: I'd call that a workaround, not a solution. Did you report this bug to ArenaNet so it can be fixed? Looks like the font used for the Large setting is broken.